# Crop darkspace from photo in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

This post is an extension of a question asked a couple years ago here:
[Crop whitespace from image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669683/crop-whitespace-from-image-in-php)

That post does a magnificent job of explaining how to use php to crop pure white space from around an image.  The issue here is that it expects "pure white" around the image.  Here is what i am trying to do and how it differs:

I am using my cell phone as a "scanner" to take pictures of documents and then upload them to my server (don't worry...there is no "secret agent" stuff going on here...it is actually mostly receipts from lunches and sometimes business cards).  In my case I always try to use a dark background to contrast with the light color paper.  The images never come out with "pure" black/white colors however.  My image is always in JPG format.  I am experimenting with the code referenced above (but swapped to test for dark/black border) and wonder if there is a way to generalize the function to apply more broadly?  I can install ImageMagick and use trimImage and some other stuff, but would rather stick to GD since that will be more useful to more StackOverflow users.  Here is what i thought of so far:

IDEA #1: convert the image to greyscale and crank the contrast very high...do the comparison there (presumable against pure black at that point)...then use the found coordinates on the original (non-greyscale) image.  What do you think...good approach?  Would it work?
I would use imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE); and then imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -90);

IDEA #2:  Go generic.  This is the idea I need the most help with.  It would be really cool if i could automatically detect the approximate range of colors from the border.  The idea would be to sample a pixel (or several) from each of the four corners and then "average" them to figure out the background.  This would mean that one day if i wanted to take the photo against a brown background, or a red background, or a green background...no problem.  I think that the first step in this direction would involve the use of imagecolorclosest() but frankly am in WAY over my head on how to select, compare, average, and then re-compare the colors.  Ideally there would be a way to just plug in some of this logic to the original function (from link above) and it would then be able to work generically regardless of what background color is in the image (assuming it is reasonably consistent) and would work with a photo (thus an image where the background color is not absolutely the same color value all the way across).

So...two part question: Is my IDEA #1 the best approach and are there any problems i should be aware of or suggestions on improvement/implementation?  And...does anyone want to give a go at IDEA #2 and at least give me enough code to get moving in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i went ahead and played around with IDEA#1 and it is working exceptionally well.  I am all set and need no further help at the moment...though still think that IDEA #2 is a better all-around solution, so if anyone wants to provide some pointers for it, i will play around with the ideas and try to come up with additional code examples to post here.  For now, here is my working version of IDEA#1 as described above and tested on several cell-phone images:

```
//MANY THANKS TO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669683/crop-whitespace-from-image-in-php    

$OriginalImageFileLocation = 'sampleimage.jpg';

    //load the image into a variable (and throw an error if image does not exist)
    if( !$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("$OriginalImageFileLocation") )
    { exit("Could not use image $OriginalImageFileLocation"); } 

    // This function only can detect the background if it is "pure black"...so convert to greyscale then crank the contrast
    imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -100);


    //find the size of the borders
    $b_top = 0;
    $b_btm = 0;
    $b_lft = 0;
    $b_rt = 0;

    //top
    for(; $b_top < imagesy($img); ++$b_top) {
      for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); ++$x) {
        if(imagecolorat($img, $x, $b_top) != 0x000000) {
           break 2; //out of the 'top' loop
        }
      }
    }

    //bottom
    for(; $b_btm < imagesy($img); ++$b_btm) {
      for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); ++$x) {
        if(imagecolorat($img, $x, imagesy($img) - $b_btm-1) != 0x000000) {
           break 2; //out of the 'bottom' loop
        }
      }
    }

    //left
    for(; $b_lft < imagesx($img); ++$b_lft) {
      for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); ++$y) {
        if(imagecolorat($img, $b_lft, $y) != 0x000000) {
           break 2; //out of the 'left' loop
        }
      }
    }

    //right
    for(; $b_rt < imagesx($img); ++$b_rt) {
      for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); ++$y) {
        if(imagecolorat($img, imagesx($img) - $b_rt-1, $y) != 0x000000) {
           break 2; //out of the 'right' loop
        }
      }
    }

    //now re-initialize the original image since the greyscaled version was just for gathering cordinates
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg("$OriginalImageFileLocation");

    // OPTIONAL: make the final image a bit prettier (and greyscale for long-term consistency)
    imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS, +15);
    imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -20);


    //copy the contents, excluding the border
    $newimg = imagecreatetruecolor( imagesx($img)-($b_lft+$b_rt), imagesy($img)-($b_top+$b_btm) );
    imagecopy($newimg, $img, 0, 0, $b_lft, $b_top, imagesx($newimg), imagesy($newimg));

    //finally, output the image
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($newimg);
```