# Codeigniter Trim Image

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-processing

I am using the upload class that codeigniter comes with:

```
$config['upload_path'] = getcwd() . '/public/images';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';
$config['encrypt_name'] = true;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    echo $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

}
else
{
    echo $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
}
```

It works fine uploading the file but now I would like to trim all the extra white space from the image. I looked at the image manipulation class but it does not seem to do it. So I looked around and found this [Crop whitespace from image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669683/crop-whitespace-from-image-in-php). I am unsure though how to put the two together. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the image manipulation class doesn't support doing that.

You can, however, extend the library (bottom of http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) and add a new method based on the code from the link you found already.

Here, I was bored at work, extend CI's image manipulation lib and add this method:

```
public function trim_whitespace($color = 'FFFFFF')
{
    //load the image
    $img = $this->image_create_gd();

    //find the size of the borders
    $b_top = 0;
    $b_btm = 0;
    $b_lft = 0;
    $b_rt = 0;

    //top
    for(; $b_top < imagesy($img); ++$b_top) {
        for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); ++$x) {
            if(imagecolorat($img, $x, $b_top) != '0x'.$color) {
                break 2; //out of the 'top' loop
            }
        }
    }

    //bottom
    for(; $b_btm < imagesy($img); ++$b_btm) {
        for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); ++$x) {
            if(imagecolorat($img, $x, imagesy($img) - $b_btm-1) != '0x'.$color) {
                break 2; //out of the 'bottom' loop
            }
        }
    }

    //left
    for(; $b_lft < imagesx($img); ++$b_lft) {
        for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); ++$y) {
            if(imagecolorat($img, $b_lft, $y) != '0x'.$color) {
                break 2; //out of the 'left' loop
            }
        }
    }

    //right
    for(; $b_rt < imagesx($img); ++$b_rt) {
        for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); ++$y) {
            if(imagecolorat($img, imagesx($img) - $b_rt-1, $y) != '0x'.$color) {
                break 2; //out of the 'right' loop
            }
        }
    }

    //copy the contents, excluding the border
    $newimg = imagecreatetruecolor(
    imagesx($img)-($b_lft+$b_rt), imagesy($img)-($b_top+$b_btm));

    imagecopy($newimg, $img, 0, 0, $b_lft, $b_top, imagesx($newimg), imagesy($newimg));

    //  Output the image
    if ($this->dynamic_output == TRUE)
    {
        $this->image_display_gd($newimg);
    }
    else
    {
        // Or save it
        if ( ! $this->image_save_gd($newimg))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// load extended image lib
$this->load->library('image_lib');

// configure image lib
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image']  = 'path/to/source.img';
$config['new_image']     = 'path/to/output.img';

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->trim_whitespace('38ff7e'); // set colour to trim, defaults to white (ffffff)
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

It's worth noting that even though it will work, you really shouldn't use this as a dynamic_output, do the trim on save otherwise it will just slow everything down. Also, it is looking for just 1 colour value (although, that is a limitation from the code you posted, there may be better functions for this out there) so if it's a compressed jpg you might have trouble getting all of the whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for the help...I am a little confused by how I should call the image and when. Should I run what I have up there and then on successful upload run the manipulation class? if yes then should I upload it to a temp folder then run the manipulation class which will move it into the correct folder? Thanks for the help

Comment: Yep, run the manipulation in your else{} when upload is successful. I'm not sure there is any reason to use an extra temp folder in between unless you need to keep the unaltered image somewhere else. If you set the image_lib's source_image to your upload_path + the 'file_name' that gets returned in $this->upload->data() and new_image to the same thing it will simply overwrite the originally uploaded one.

Answer (score 0):

To use the ImageMagick you should add the function to the image_lib.php:

```
public function trimimg()
    {
        $protocol =  'image_process_'.$this->image_library;     
        return $this->$protocol('trimimg');
    }
```

and then add to the function

```
public function image_process_imagemagick($action = 'resize')
    {
        // Do we have a vaild library path?     
        if ($this->library_path === '')
        {
            $this->set_error('imglib_libpath_invalid');
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ( ! preg_match('/convert$/i', $this->library_path))
        {
            $this->library_path = rtrim($this->library_path, '/').'/convert';
        }

        // Execute the command
        $cmd = $this->library_path.' -quality '.$this->quality;

        if ($action === 'crop')
        {
            $cmd .= ' -crop '.$this->width.'x'.$this->height.'+'.$this->x_axis.'+'.$this->y_axis;
        }
        elseif ($action === 'rotate')
        {
            $cmd .= ($this->rotation_angle === 'hor' OR $this->rotation_angle === 'vrt')
                    ? ' -flop'
                    : ' -rotate '.$this->rotation_angle;
        }
        elseif ($action === 'trimimg')
        {
            $cmd .= ' -trim';
        }
```

the last elseif.

Then

```
$this->image_lib->trimimg())
```