# trim whitespace around PNG in PHP

Tags: php, png, gd

I am using code very similar to (does the same thing as) the answer to this question: [Crop whitespace from image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669683/crop-whitespace-from-image-in-php). I have tried this exact code as well, to the same effect:

I find that it does not work (does not trim white space) with a PNG source, even if the background of the PNG is true white (not transparent). I can send the output to `imagepng` without issue, but if the image source is `imagecreatefrompng`, nothing is trimmed.

Is there a reliable way to trim whitespace from a PNG using GD? Or perhaps a way to convert the color white to transparent and trim that instead? Or, other solution...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a totally untested guess. However, I would assume that alpha transparency is causing the issue. The answer that you mentioned might need a bit of work.

Perhaps try using `imagecopymerge()` to lay the image over a white canvas, and then go through the steps mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Actually this did work - I had introduced a separate error into my code. It doesn't seem like the most elegant or resource-friendly solution, but it does work.

Comment: @k3davis Yeah, GD is not the most elegant of libraries :( I have put the functions behind a facade when I've used it in the past, with a separate class for each of the image types, to iron out the inconsistencies. This let me do something like `$image->cropWhitespace()`, without having to worry about whether it have alpha transparency.