# Trim white colour from thousands of images

Tags: image

I have about 60,000 product images from various suppliers. Some of the images are excellent in that the product image extends all the way to the edge of the image while some have massive amounts of white colour, almost like a massive white border either above, below, or to both sides of the product. The amount of white is different per image so I can't use FastStone to crop the image as this only allows me to crop with predefined values.

I need some kind of automated program which will figure out where the product image starts and trim or crop the image accordingly.

e.g. I'd be happy if there were 2 pixels of white to the top, left, right and bottom of every image.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to looking into doing this through Javascript, which as it turns out is possible providing the images are on your own site, but in the end I went with this solution:

[Crop whitespace from image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669683/crop-whitespace-from-image-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ImageMagick convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) to trim arbitrary amount of white in the images

```
convert input_image_name -trim output_image_name
```

If you use a unix-like OS, you can easily script it for all the images

```
for i in *
do
   convert  ${i} -trim trimmed_${i}
done
```

Comment: Hi - I need it to automatically figure out the arbitrary amount of white that needs removing.

Comment: Hi David. Maybe I did not understand your question, but this is automatic: you do not have to specify the amount of pixels to remove, it just crops the image to remove all the white pixels at the borders.