# php - crop whitespace and resize image

Tags: php, crop, image-resizing

I would like to know the best way to crop the whitespace from an image and also dynamically resize it to given dimensions maintaining the aspect ratio. The method should be fairly lightweight because I need it for displaying many images in a page (product listings with 30-50 images/page).

I use [this script](http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/) for resizing images and I've also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669683/crop-whitespace-from-image-in-php) that does exactly what I need, but I'm not sure on how I could combine both scripts.

Any help or alternatives will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use ImageMagick?

Comment: If it does the job, sure, why not?

Comment: Take a look at the [Wideimage library](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/), it works on top of gd2 and imagemagick and has [autocrop](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/demo/index.php?demo=autoCrop) by default.

Comment: Can it crop only the whitespace though?

Comment: With the [$base_color](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/doc/WideImage/WideImage_Image.html#methodautoCrop) parameter you can set it to any color or you can let it use the top-left pixel by default.

Comment: Could you kindly give me a hint on how to implement this in my pages? I've included WideImage.php in my files, I tried a simple call:  $image = WideImage::load("images/products/1.jpg");
echo $resized = $image->resize(400, 300); and I get chars in my browser instead of an image. What am I missing?