# GD Image Library merge 2 images with "Collision Detection"

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

I have two images, large text on white background. The length varies but the text is always aligned to the left, so there is basically free space on the right side of each image. I now want to merge these two images into one and move them as closely together as possible without having the texts "collide".

I thought of somehow checking on a per pixel column base if there's another color than white (starting from the right side), so I know after how many pixels the text starts.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? And with that then, what is your *concrete* programming question? Until now you've only left some requirements, so this sounds more like a google request than a real question.

Comment: I tried taking the text length (in characters, strlen() ) and applying that to my merging function, but because the text gets distorted (its for a captcha) this doesnt work and sometimes they overlap

Comment: Yes obviously. You didn't really thought it would solve that, right? A better variant is imagettfbox however it can't beat the captcha. You might want to remove white parts of the page which you can search here on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, neat function to strip all the whitespace from an image:

```
function stripWhitespace($img) {
        //find the size of the borders
$b_top = 0;
$b_btm = 0;
$b_lft = 0;
$b_rt = 0;

//top
for(; $b_top < imagesy($img); ++$b_top) {
  for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); ++$x) {
    if(imagecolorat($img, $x, $b_top) != 0xFFFFFF) {
       break 2; //out of the 'top' loop
    }
  }
}

//bottom
for(; $b_btm < imagesy($img); ++$b_btm) {
  for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); ++$x) {
    if(imagecolorat($img, $x, imagesy($img) - $b_btm-1) != 0xFFFFFF) {
       break 2; //out of the 'bottom' loop
    }
  }
}

//left
for(; $b_lft < imagesx($img); ++$b_lft) {
  for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); ++$y) {
    if(imagecolorat($img, $b_lft, $y) != 0xFFFFFF) {
       break 2; //out of the 'left' loop
    }
  }
}

//right
for(; $b_rt < imagesx($img); ++$b_rt) {
  for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); ++$y) {
    if(imagecolorat($img, imagesx($img) - $b_rt-1, $y) != 0xFFFFFF) {
       break 2; //out of the 'right' loop
    }
  }
}

//copy the contents, excluding the border
$newimg = imagecreatetruecolor(
    imagesx($img)-($b_lft+$b_rt), imagesy($img)-($b_top+$b_btm));

imagecopy($newimg, $img, 0, 0, $b_lft, $b_top, imagesx($newimg), imagesy($newimg));
return $newimg;
    }
```

From here: [Crop whitespace from image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669683/crop-whitespace-from-image-in-php)