# Performance improvements PHP GD resize and trim image background keeping the correct ratio

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd, image-resizing

I developed an image resizing & trimming class using PHP GD library. I used [skibulks image trim script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669683/crop-whitespace-from-image-in-php) to trim the image background in the first step and scale the image in the second step to the needed sizes (maintaining the original ratio).

**Question:** Is it really necessary to do the first `imagecopy` job after getting the new trimmed image sizes from the `$this->_trimBackground()` function to recreate the image first by `imagecopy` with the new trimmed sizes (and resize it afterwards again)?  **Or**, is it possible to merge this job with the following resizing part `imagecopyresampled`?

Are there other possible performance improvements possible which I don't know?  Every performance suggestion is welcome!

**Function 1:**

```
/**
 * Resize image file
 * 
 * @param   string $filepath the image filepath
 * @param   integer $width the width to resize
 * @param   integer $height the height to resize
 * @return  (image blob|boolean status)
 * @throws  Asset_Model_Image_Exception
 */
private function _resizeImageByFilepathAndReturn($filepath, $width, $height) {

    list($imageWidth, $imageHeight, $imageType) = getimagesize($filepath);

   switch($imageType) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $gdImage = imagecreatefromgif($filepath);
            break;
      case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath);
            break;
      case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $gdImage = imagecreatefrompng($filepath);
            break;
      default:
                return false;
   }

   if($box = $this->_trimBackground($gdImage)) {

    $gdTrimmed = imagecreatetruecolor($box['w'], $box['h']);
    imagecopy($gdTrimmed, $gdImage, 0, 0, $box['l'], $box['t'], $box['w'], $box['h']);

    $imageWidth = $box['w'];
    $imageHeight = $box['h'];
    $gdImage = $gdTrimmed;

    unset($gdTrimmed);

   }

   if($imageWidth <= $width && $imageHeight <= $height) {

    $fwidth = $imageWidth;
        $fheight = $imageHeight;

   } else {

        $wscale = $width / $imageWidth;
        $hscale = $height / $imageHeight;
        $scale = min($wscale, $hscale);
        $fwidth = $scale * $imageWidth;
        $fheight = $scale * $imageHeight;

   }

   $gdThumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

   imagefill($gdThumbnail, 0, 0, 0x00FFFFFF);

   imagecopyresampled($gdThumbnail, $gdImage, ($width - $fwidth) / 2, ($height - $fheight) / 2, 0, 0, $fwidth, $fheight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);

   ob_start();
   imagejpeg($gdThumbnail, null, 90);
   $image = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();

   imagedestroy($gdImage);
   imagedestroy($gdThumbnail);

   return $image;

}
```

**Function 2:**

```
/**
 * Trim image background
 * 
 * @param $gdImage image ressource
 */
private function _trimBackground($gdImage){

    $hex = imagecolorat($gdImage, 0,0);

    $width = imagesx($gdImage);
    $height = imagesy($gdImage);

    $bTop = 0;
    $bLft = 0;
    $bBtm = $height - 1;
    $bRt = $width - 1;

    for(; $bTop < $height; ++$bTop) {
        for($x = 0; $x < $width; ++$x) {
            if(imagecolorat($gdImage, $x, $bTop) != $hex) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    if($bTop == $height) {
        return false;
    }

    for(; $bBtm >= 0; --$bBtm) {
        for($x = 0; $x < $width; ++$x) {
            if(imagecolorat($gdImage, $x, $bBtm) != $hex) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    for(; $bLft < $width; ++$bLft) {
        for($y = $bTop; $y <= $bBtm; ++$y) {
            if(imagecolorat($gdImage, $bLft, $y) != $hex) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    for(; $bRt >= 0; --$bRt) {
        for($y = $bTop; $y <= $bBtm; ++$y) {
            if(imagecolorat($gdImage, $bRt, $y) != $hex) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    $bBtm++;
    $bRt++;

    return array('l' => $bLft, 't' => $bTop, 'r' => $bRt, 'b' => $bBtm, 'w' => $bRt - $bLft, 'h' => $bBtm - $bTop);

}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com may be a better location for this question

Comment: thank you for the hint jeztah! I also created it there http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21228/performance-improvements-php-gd-resize-and-trim-image-background-keeping-the-cor

Comment: Is there any reason why do you optimise for performance?

Comment: What? Why i'm optimizing for performance? Because there are about 10 Mio. images and time is money? :-)

Comment: Are you bound to using GD yourself? Do you have access to the IMagick module? Or access to the program convert? (ImageMagick also) I'd bet using any of those would give you a really good performance boost. (We handle a huge amount of images like this, backed by a gearman jobqueue and split over a couple of application servers)

Comment: I'd use Imagick instead, I have used it before on heavy images & it works very well.

Comment: I have tried your code & what's getting longer than expected is your "_trimBackground" function, that's because you're going through image 4 times to calculate the left, right, top, bottom so depending on image contents the function might return quickly or might get stuck there for too long. Currently I have no solution for this, but if you can come up with something that would calculate this in 1 go it would be faster for sure.

Comment: On the other hand you might try to resize the image to an appropriate size before passing it to this function so you'll have less time consumed to generate the thumbnail

Answer (score 5):

imagecopy() copies a section of your $gdImage to $gdTrimmed and a couple of lines later     overwrites $gdImage with $gdTrimmed.

> Is it really necessary to do the first imagecopy?

That's something you should ask yourself.

Using `imagedestroy()` function instead of `unset()` might greatly improve your performance. Here's a useful comment on [imagedestroy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php):

> Reusing an image variable does NOT clear the old data out of memory! 
>   You must use imagedestroy() to clear the data out.  (I don't know if
>   unset() works as well).
>
> Also note that the image data in memory is raw, so don't base how much
>   memory you are using based on the original filesize of the compressed
>   image (such as jpeg or png).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Using imagedestroy() has improved performance by 40%.