# API to clean scanned documents

Tags: api, ocr, crop

I have a system in PHP, and i will receive photos from users, that are scanned photos of their personal documents... and i want to smart remove (auto crop) the boundaries of the photos, to leave ONLY the personal document (as a drivers license).

I spent hours looking, but were not able to find an API service that does that...i ll i can find was SDK for ios or android...

Any one has a suggestion?

I would want to replicate what dropbox did:

https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2016/08/fast-and-accurate-document-detection-for-scanning/

Thanks

Comment: Are they complex documents or single items from a scanner that you want to remove the outlining whitespace from what I guess I'll refer to as the scanner canvas/surface area? Rectangles only type of situation?

Give this a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669683/crop-whitespace-from-image-in-php

Comment: thanks, but i need something more complex, to remove the border that are not only white....it is a picture taken by a phone of a person holding a drivers license, an example.

Comment: i was able to find something that helped me a lote...maybe it help somebody else...:   https://github.com/vipul-sharma20/document-scanner

Answer (score 0):

[Filestack](https://www.filestack.com/) provides these services. In particular, the [Document Detection](https://www.filestack.com/docs/transformations/intelligence/document-detection/) endpoint has the following description:

> You can detect your document in the image, transform it to fully fit the image...